# LinkageError - loader constraint violation - when resolving method "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()"

Tags: java, tomcat, maven-2, classloader, slf4j

I am getting following error:

`ContextListenerjava.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method
"org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder.getLoggerFactory()Lorg/slf4j/ILoggerFactory;" the class loader 'org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader@4d1cc3c3 (urls: ['], parents: [)'java.net.URLClassLoader@4fccd51b']) of the current class, org/slf4j/LoggerFactory, and the class loader 'System (urls: [''file:/usr/lib/jvm/jvm_8/jvm_8/lib/jvmx.jar',
 'file:/usr/lib/jvm/jvm_8/jvm_8/lib/tools.jar',
 'file:/
....`

It seems my cloud platform by default packages `slf4j`, and I am getting this error because I am also putting slf4j as dependency in my pom file and two different class loaders are loading `slf4j`

The way I resolved the issue was to change the scope of dependency in pom to provided.

But the side effect is I am not able to run it on my local tomcat as it doesn't find slf4j library.

What can be done in this case so that my war runs fine on both my cloud platform and on my local tomcat?

Answer (score 0):

You can use different profiles in your pom.xml.

Example for SAP Cloud Platform:

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <properties>
                <packaging.type>jar</packaging.type>
            </properties>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>scp</id>
        <properties>
            <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
        </properties>
        <build>
            <finalName>LoraConnector</finalName>
        </build>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

You can use a profile using "Run configurations" in Eclipse (or another tool) or when you're building the war file:

```
mvn -P scp clean package
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using spring-boot-starter-web-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar,then you need to exclude jul-to-slf4j-1.7.22.jar,jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar.These two jar have conflict slf4j-api. 
`<plugin> <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId> <version>2.6</version> <configuration>
<packagingExcludes>
WEB-INF/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.22.jar,WEB-INF/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.22.jar
</packagingExcludes>
</configuration>
</plugin>`